# Magento - Is it possible to attach a file to a transactional email?

Tags: email, magento, transactions

I need to attach a file to a transactional email. Basically I have a cron job that generates a report and needs to it email to an admin user.

I was hoping something like this exists:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                ->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>1))
                ->createAttachment($file)
                ->sendTransactional($templateID, $sender, $email, “Admin", $vars);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using? The reason I ask is that the email code has changed in the most recent version, breaking my 'auto attach invoice PDF' code so I am interested in what solution you find (if you are on >1.4).

Comment: Im on Magento version. 1.4.1.1

Comment: Sounds like you are there already. I would like it if you could put your finished block together as I too have an update prices module that could do with emailing the boss when the prices have been updated (it runs on a cron).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that magento uses the zend_mail frame work. You can call the getMail function to access this framework to add an attachement.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

**Example**

```
$transactionalEmail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>1));

$transactionalEmail->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents,'text/csv')->filename = $filename;

$transactionalEmail->sendTransactional($templateID, $sender, $email, "Admin", $vars);
```

Comment: what is $fileContents?

Comment: This is file_get_contents($filePath)